# How to make Intel QSV FFmpeg to run on GPU in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: graphics, video, intel, ffmpeg

In ubuntu 14.04, my ffmpeg configurations are,

```
ffmpeg version ebe0fa0 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-opencl --enable-nonfree --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libaacplus
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

Using this command,

> ffmpeg -i /home/M.mp4 -c:v h264_qsv -preset:v faster /home/out.avi

the CPU% has been more than 90 (375%). Thus it is running in CPU.

I studied that Intel QSV is running in die processor, which is almost on CPU. ffmpeg is mainly for hardware accelerations. So is it possible to make it run on Intel GPU in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the CPU is nearly fully utilized does NOT mean that it's not also doing work in the GPU as well.  Not **all** of the encoding work is moved to the GPU, but rather the GPU accelerates and offloads some of the tasks.  There may be tools available to directly query the utilization of the **GPU** component (I don't know of them off the top of my head) -- these would confirm that your GPU is doing some of the work.

On my particular machine, the h264_qsv codec runs approximately 5x faster in frames/second terms than the libx264 codec, even though in both cases the reported "CPU utilization" is near 100%.

```
[lwobker:/dtop/nobackup/]$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | egrep 'model name'
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz

[lwobker:/dtop/nobackup]$ ffmpeg -hide_banner -codecs | egrep 'qsv' | egrep '264'
 DEV.LS h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264 h264_qsv ) (encoders: libx264 libx264rgb h264_nvenc h264_qsv nvenc nvenc_h264 )
```